# CSS nth-child(odd) not working

Tags: html, css

I need to alternate the background color of the class `jl-member-info` but this doesn’t work. I have this code:

```css
.uk-grid .jl-member-item .jl-member-info:nth-child(odd) {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0.9rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 198, 197, 0.89);
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -95px;
}

.uk-grid .jl-member-item .jl-member-info:nth-child(even) {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0.9rem;
  background-color: #090963;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -95px;
}
```

```html
<div class="jl-member ">
  <div class=" uk-grid-large uk-grid uk-grid-width-small-1-2 uk-grid-width-medium-1-2 uk-grid-width-large-1-4" data-uk-grid-margin="">
    <div class="jl-member-item default uk-row-first">
      <div class="jl-member-item-img">
        <img class="uk-overlay-spin" src="/templates/g5_helium/custom/images/Alain.jpg?595f26c4">
      </div>
      <div class="jl-member-info">
        <div class="jl-member-name">Alain</div>
        <div class="jl-member-role">Maire</div>
        <div class="jl-member-desc"><a href="mailto:mail@test.fr"><span class="cloaked_email">mail@test.fr</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="jl-member-item default">
      <div class="jl-member-item-img">
        <img class="uk-overlay-spin" src="/templates/g5_helium/custom/images/Alain.jpg?595f26c4">
      </div>
      <div class="jl-member-info">
        <div class="jl-member-name">Alain</div>
        <div class="jl-member-role">Maire</div>
        <div class="jl-member-desc"><a href="mailto:mail@test.fr"><span class="cloaked_email">mail@test.fr</span></a>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="jl-member-item default">
      <div class="jl-member-item-img">
        <img class="uk-overlay-spin" src="/templates/g5_helium/custom/images/Alain.jpg?595f26c4">
      </div>
      <div class="jl-member-info">
        <div class="jl-member-name">Alain</div>
        <div class="jl-member-role">Maire</div>
        <div class="jl-member-desc"><a href="mailto:mail@test.fr"><span class="cloaked_email">mail@test.fr</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to recode like this, because you have only one `.jl-member-info` in `.jl-member-item` it will always be odd!

```
.uk-grid .jl-member-item .jl-member-info {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 0.9rem;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -95px;
    background-color: #090963;
}

.uk-grid .jl-member-item:nth-child(odd) .jl-member-info {
    background-color: rgba(0, 198, 197, 0.89);
}
```

Comment: Would we need the !important since the second definition is after the first and it is more specific?